# Creating PairedRDD from textfiles in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a doubt with Apache Spark using Java coding. I have
a sample file in plain text composed by pairs separated by Tab char. Something like this:

```
** example.txt
1   5
2   7
5   4
**
```

and I was reading some books on the internet and they suggest this code to create a *pairedRDD* using the first column of the line as the key, and the second column as the value. So they use the *Tuple2* (from scala).

But I can't understand why all the examples I see, create the tuple, initializing the object with the value as the **whole** line. Because the key is only the [0] of the *x.split()[0]* function. and the value seems to be the whole line.

Is this correct? or should I replace it by *x.split()[1]* (for the value)?

The code below is what I found in many example sources on the web.

```
PairFunction<String, String, String> keyData =   new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {

    public Tuple2<String, String> call(String x) {

    return new Tuple2(x.split(” “)[0], x);

}
```

Comment: @HermanZ please read `spark-java` tag description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-java and consider removing it from your post. `spark-java` is not about Spark's Java API but about this framework http://sparkjava.com/ which has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's only an example. You can return x[1] or x. I do not know the exact context, but I have seen this style of example here in the past as far as I can remember.

So, your choice, no right or wrong. For me, I would assume the x[1], but equally the x[0] can be seen as the key to a line.

The lesson here is: you can do both. From there on you can **reduce(ByKey)** or **groupByKey**, for example. That's what a a PairedRDD can do.